# Write multiple JSON lines to JSON file

Tags: python, json, multi-document

I have a code that needs to read a JSON file with multiple lines, i.e:

```
{"c1-line1": "value", "c2-line1": "value"}
{"c1-line2": "value", "c2-line2": "value"}...
```

and, after change the keys values (already working), I need to write a new json file with these multiple lines, i.e:

```
{"newc1-line1": "value", "newc2-line1": "value"}
{"newc1-line2": "value", "newc2-line2": "value"}...
```

My problem is that my code are just writing the last value readed:

```
{"newc1-line2": "value", "newc2-line2": "value"}
```

My code:

```
def main():
   ... # changeKeyValueCode
   writeFile(data)
 
def writeFile(data):
   with open('new_file.json', 'w') as f:
       json.dump(data, f)
```

I already tried with `json.dumps` and just `f.write('')` or `f.write('\n')`

I know that *data* in `writeFile()` is correctly with each line value.

How can I resolve this, please?

Comment: `open('new_file.json', 'w')` opens file for writing, if you call `writeFile` in a loop it will overwrite previous content, try calling `open` with `a` flag, to append, so it will look like this: `open('new_file.json', 'a')`. Anyway, opening file in a loop isn't that good, if this is the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def main():
   ... # changeKeyValueCode
   writeFile(data)
 
def writeFile(data):
   with open('new_file.json', 'a') as f:
       json.dump(data, f)
```

> with open('new_file.json', 'a')

open file with (**a**), it will search the file if found append data to the end, else it will create empty file and then append data.